# How to override internal functions?

Tags: vb.net, oop, inheritance, overriding

I want to replace xxxx function in m function in inherit class
how can do this
here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim h As New y5
        h.xxxx()
        h.m()
    End Sub

    Class x
        Friend Sub xxxx()
            MsgBox("JJ")
        End Sub
        Sub m()
            xxxx()
        End Sub
    End Class
    Class y5
        Inherits x
        Friend Sub xxxx()
            MsgBox("KK")
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I ~think~ you want `KK` to appear when `h.m()` is executed?...instead of `JJ`?

If that's the case, then you need [overrideable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/overridable?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(vb.Overridable)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.7.2)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) and [overrides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/overrides?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(vb.Overrides)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.7.2)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue), like this:

```
Class x
    Friend Overridable Sub xxxx()
        MsgBox("JJ")
    End Sub
    Sub m()
        xxxx()
    End Sub
End Class
Class y5
    Inherits x
    Friend Overrides Sub xxxx()
        MsgBox("KK")
    End Sub
End Class
```